# create a WebApp using React, Node and Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jsx

I need a little help with my WebApp
So i started working with NodeJs and Express and now i want to integrate some React on my EditProfile page.

So how can i do it ?

I tried somthing simple like

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But it did not work

Searched some help here and there but couldn't find any simple exemple for me to understand.

Can anyone give me tips to to help buit a spa with react and node ?

Comment: have you required the libraries? `var React = require('react');`
`var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');`

Comment: @TomaszBubała Yes i did, still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asume you are using webpack as your bundler (it's the one i am more confortable with so i can give you better guidance), if you dont have webpack:

```
sudo npm install -g webpack@1.12.13
```

First of all you need to be sure you have the react and react-dom library installed, if not go to your project folder and run this command(This is the version i am currently using in a project but you can use another):

```
npm install --save react@0.14.7 react-dom@0.14.7
```

Secondly, you need Babel to transpile the ES6 code, not mandatory but way more confortable with Babel, this are the dependencies you need in your development environment:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack@1.12.13 babel-core@6.5.1 babel-loader@6.2.2 babel-preset-es2015@6.5.0 babel-preset-react@6.5.0
```

I know this can be tedious, so bear with me....

In your development setup you are probably going to use ES6 features, this is when a bundler like webpack and Babel comes handy, Babel is going to transpile your ES6 code into ES5(Implemented in every browser) and Webpack is going to bundle all your files with require along with your dependencies and generate a bundle.js(your whole app).

Lets configure Webpack!
In the root of your project you'll find(or create) a webpack.config.js file, the content should look something like this for a very simple setup:

```
  module.exports = {
  entry: './public/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    // Thanks to this aliases we can reference component files without specifiying the path each time
    alias: {
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
  //Added the loader into modules
    loaders: [
      {
      //Loader Name
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        //Specifies what we whant the loader to make with our files
        query: {
        //We told Babel to take our files and transforms them trough react and then the es2015
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        },
        //Regular expresion to find the files we want to parse within our project
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        //Specifies the directories we do not want to parse.
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Now that you have all the basic setup you can bundle everything using the following command:

```
webpack
```

You can find a boilerplate project i made with instructions on how to run it at my github profile, it has a nice folder structure and a express server for you to run your tests. That should make everything clearer.

https://github.com/agustincastro/ReactBoilerplate

I hope it helped you to get the basic setup up and running so you can play around with React.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer !! Idid everything you mentioned but couldn't bundle everything with 
    webpack

Comment: What was the error? maybe try to download the boilerplate and run the example. If i can be of any help don't hesitate to ask

Comment: it says "'webpack' is not recognized as an internal command
Or external, an executable program or a batch file." 
Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Sounds like you dont have webpack properly installed: run the following command to check your installed version "npm view webpack version" if you dont have it install it with "sudo npm install -g webpack@1.12.13"

Comment: it says " 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal command
Or external, an executable program or a batch file. "

Comment: Are you using Windows or a Unix based OS? if you are using windows try "npm install -g webpack"

Comment: I'm using Windows, i used 'npm install -g webpack' and still the commande "webpack" is not recognized

Comment: Ok, it's propbably an npm or node issue, are you sure you have node.js and npm correctly installed globally? that is the first thing you need to check: "node -v"  .... if that isnt correct here is a good guide on how to install it correctly. After you are sure you have node and npm installed try the process again. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows

Comment: i've worked with node for about 4 or 5 months now and my npm was good til now. "node -v" gievs me my node version v6.5.0 is it bad ?
Here's what i've done til now :  https://github.com/LAsmaa/NodeReact

Comment: First things first: for some reason it looks like you don't have webpack installed globally, you need to take care of that first, as i dont have a Windows machine i cannot try it out. Secondly, in your github repo check out the webpack.config.js file, your entry does not match your project structure, if you intend to leave the app.jsx in the root of your project use "./app.jsx" (you currently have a plain js file also). But make sure all your node dependencies are correct(including webpack)

Comment: Don't worry, maybe it's easer to try to run the basic project i linked to test the environment setup. After you have it running try to migrate the configurations to your project. Hope it was useful and if youre able to make it run and fix things please accept the answer, Cheers!

Comment: I'll try this !!! If it still don't work i'll restart everyting x) !!! 
I really should change windows x) !!

Comment: I reinstalled my NodeJs, webpack is recognized now but when I run it I have this error : in the next com :p
(The app works well now)

Comment: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'root'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?
, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.

Comment: Hi, i'm glad you made it work, it's the first step in the right direction, what the message is telling you is that there is an error inside webpack.config.js. What is the project you are trying to run? if you tell me i'll take a look at the config file

Comment: here's my project https://github.com/LAsmaa/TeamDb (Withouthe webpack.config.js file ) 
What i wa to do is to make the "edit" page an spa with react !! (Seems weird but that's what i need) i added an src file for the components bu now ....

Comment: I forked your repo and added a little example (bundled component), webpack is working with that configuration, change it as you want in order to fit your project structure. But this should get you going. https://github.com/agustincastro/TeamDb

Comment: Thanks a lot :D !! Webpack works now :D !!!! 
So now i just ned to include my bundle.js file in the html file i want (And add the componene in the webpack config ) ? ._.

Comment: You got it, your bundle.js already contains your app and their dependencies(react, react-dom, etc), you just need to include it in your index.html. When you make new files for new components you can take any of these approaches: 1) include them with the path(not so elegant) 2) add an alias for every file inside the webpack.config(better) 3) resolve them as module directories also inside webpack.config(much nicer)

Comment: good !! i tried t include it in my .ejs files afted adding ReactApp.jsx in the webpack.config.jsx file , But still no hello world for me ._.

Comment: Try to inspect the html with the developer tools, render your helloworld component inside a known dom node. You're definitely in the right directions, check for errors in the console and maybe print some messages to debug. For some reason i cant run your server in my machine, so it's difficult for me to test it inside your solution, in the boilerplate inside my github profile there are some easy components like a navbar rendered, maybe you find it useful as an example of how to set everything up

Comment: I'll do this !! Thanks for everything ^^

Comment: Good luck then! i'm glad to be of help, if you can and think it corresponds please mark the answer as correct. Cheers!